# display settings zoom

Tags: display, settings

I'm using Ubuntu (don't know what version, from the past month), and accidentally changed under `settings -> display` the bar at the bottom that doing `zoom` to the environment. Now it exceeds my screen edges, so I can't reach it.

How can I undo this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again go to `Settings` -> `Display` and reset the zoom level to 1.

[image]

As for knowing the version of Ubuntu go to `Settings` -> `Details`

First check the current scaling factor by : Open `Terminal` and type the following :

`gsettings get com.ubuntu.user-interface scale-factor`

This will produce something like this :
`{'VGA1': 15}` or `{'HDMI-0': 16}`

> (**Note**: There may be multiple values such as {'VGA1': 8, 'HDMI0': 8, 'DVI1':15})

If the value is something greater than 8, it should be set to 8. This represents the default scaling factor (zoom level - 1), as far as i have discerned. (In this case, DVI1 has to be set again to value 8)

Type the following in terminal :

`gsettings set com.ubuntu.user-interface scale-factor "{'VGA1': 8}"`

> ('VGA1' has to be replaced by the appropriate display port that you get in the previous step)

Comment: That`s the scale I`ve changed?. I can`t reset the scale bar as it is outside my screen, so mouse can`t get there.

Comment: @user1262882 I have added the command line setting as well. Please check it out

Answer (score 0):

You mean you can't move your mouse to the proper spot to click on the menu/settings?

Try the "windows" button on your keyboard, it's often set to open the menu/dash, and find your "Settings" or "Display" in there (typing them might work), and then change the zoom/scale from there.